# There is no such thing as a "compiled language" or "interpreted language"

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter

"There is no such thing as a "compiled language" or "interpreted language". Whether a language implementer chooses to write a compiler, an interpreter or anything in between is an implementation detail and has nothing to do with the language. "

Is the above statement is true ?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: probably from me. Although I claim no originality. Especially the statement "a language is neither compiled nor interpreted, a language just *is*" is not originally from me, it is a quote from Shriram Krishnamurthi from an interview on Channel9 a couple of years ago. I think it was this one: http://Channel9.MSDN.Com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Web-Programming-with-Flapjax/

Comment: @jorg W Mittag : I am sorry to you, but its true i quoted it from your answer, coz i didnt  understood the underlying meaning of your statement.
i apologizes to you !

Comment: @Tuhin: My apologies about misspelling your name, it was just a typo.

Comment: Would have been good if the statements in the question were cited so we could see the context in which it was proposed and gauge the reliability, expertise  and the biases of the person saying it.  I appreciate the point, but there are languages that are _typically_ compiled and those  that are _typically_ interpreted, so the terms can usefully serve as a shorthand where exact rigour is not required.  There are also proprietary and niche languages where the single implementation is a compiler, in which case the distinction serves little purpose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is true in the strictest interpretation. You can find both a [C++ interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter) and a [Javascript compiler](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), for example. However, you will find that some types of languages (statically typed, for example) lend themselves well to native code compilation. Other languages (dynamically typed, for example) are commonly implemented using bytecode compilation combined with a virtual machine execution environment.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. Generally, both interpreters and compilers first need to parse the source code and turn it into a representation, called AST (abstract syntaxt tree). A compiler then turns the AST into executable code (through various transformations), while an interpreter might just directly 'interpret' the AST or sometimes compile and execute it (just-in-time compilation).

The statement is correct in that this has nothing to do with the language: in theory, you can write an interpreter and compiler for any language. Which one to use really depends on the use-case, scenario and environment.

A compiler has the advantage that he only need to do his job once, regardless of how often you then execute the program. An interpreter needs to parse the source every time (or do some caching), thus you have an overhead for each execution which might take way longer than the actual execution time of the final program. On the other hand, an interpreter is more flexible (it can take into amount the current environment and thus do optimizations a compiler is not allowed to do). But the differences don't stop here, these are just two obvious points.

Comment: I've written several interpreters and compilers - none of them built or used an AST.

Comment: What did you use instead ? And how did you do semantic analysis ?

Answer (score 1):

The above statement is true.

Then again, one might argue it is not true enough in the real world. If all existing implementations of a language rely on compilation, the language can legitimately be referred to as a compiled language.

Answer (score 1):

The language design has to do with the grammar for the higher-level input portion and the lower level ouput code that's executed on the target.

There's an abstract syntax tree in between the two.

Traditionally, if you write the lower level ouput code to execute on a particular hardware platform and its specific instruction set, the output is "compiled".

If someone decides to write an interpreter to act as the target, the output code is the instruction set or byte code that the interpreter expects.  The additional level of indirection means that the interpreted code can run on any hardware platform that has an interpreter implementation.

So the statement is correct if we call "language design" the grammar and the lexer/parser piece.

It's not strictly correct if we're talking about the code generator.

It's possible to emit a particular language as both interpreted and compiled simply by calling different code generators to walk the AST.

So perhaps that's how the distinction is blurred.  But I think it's still there.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. Nobody is denying the existence of compilers and interpreters. What is being denied is the existence of compiled languages and interpreted languages. A language is just a set of abstract mathematical rules. A language isn't compiled or interpreted. A language just *is*. As evidence, just take one of the gazillions of programming languages for which *no* implementation exists. (Say, Smalltalk-71 or Modula-1.)

Comment: I'm saying pretty much what everyone else is saying.  How is it that I'm singled out as the one who is misunderstanding?  I'm talking about the underlying implementation details, but coming to the same conclusion as most of the other respondents.

Answer (score 0):

Its true only in the sense that ultimately both compiled and interpreted languages must generate machine code.  It does have an effect on the language in so far as traditionally certain paradigms are easier in one over the other.  For example, in general, closures or blocks are easier to implement in inter5preted languages than compiled languages.  This is true since there is effectively no differnece between compile time and runtime scoping in interpreted languages.  Thus dynamic scoping TENDS to be easier to implement in interpreted languages.

Comment: Purely interpreted languages never generate machine code.  Rather, each statement will be processed using the equivalent of either an if-ifelse-else tree or a switch-case statement.  The interpreter doesn't generate any machine code from the statements it examines; rather, it simply does the appropriate actions directly.

Answer (score 0):

A given implementation of a language will be either a "pure" compiler (whose output is executed by a processor as code), a "pure" interpreter (each statement is examined for the first time, in raw-source form, as it is executed, and nothing about the interpretation is cached), or a hybrid between the two.  It's pretty easy to distinguish the "pure" cases from the hybrids, but some hybrids are 'closer' to being compiled than others; the lines between a 'compiled' hybrid versus an 'interpreted' one can be pretty fuzzy.

I don't think any language is in substantial use, other than assembly language (for which the term "assembler" is usually used in preference to "compiler"), which could not be implemented at least somewhat practically in an hybrid interpreter (performance of a "pure" interpreter is apt to be horrible with any but the most trivial looping constructs).  There are some languages, however, which allow for dynamic code generation in ways that would not be amenable to compilation.

Incidentally, when I say "raw source" form, I do not always mean text format.  My first programmable calculator had 99 program steps, each of which could be configured with a keystroke or one of a few special sequencing instructions.  The program would never exist in a human-readable text form per se, but rather as a sequence of key numbers.  Nonetheless, I would describe that as a purely-interpreted "language" since each program step was evaluated entirely independently.

Answer (score 0):

The whole compiler/interpreter thing is sort of dependent on what your intentions for your program are. A compiled program is one that is turned into machine code. An interpreter is used to read an intermediary language and run it on the machine. For instance, when you compile Java, it is turned into the Java Bytecode and is read and run by the interpreter (which also accounts for the speed disadvantage in comparison to C++).

I don't really think your statement about it having nothing to do with the language is entirely true. One of the main things about Java is that it is supposed to be runnable on different architectures. If it were compiled that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: "A compiled program is one that is turned into machine code". Compilers don't always target machine code. For example, the C# and OCaml compilers generate bytecodes for virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that, for (some?) languages that include an "eval" type statement (especially if it's not possible to determine until runtime whether a given block is code or data), even the most purely compiled version of the a given program must be partially interpreted. For such languages, it's not possible to compile them completely (the compiled code must contain an interpreter for the language).

As an example, consider the following code:

```
set s [eval {sum $a $b $c}]
```

For the above Tcl code, it's not possible to determine until runtime whether the block (inside the {}) is code or not.

Comment: -1 "must be partially interpreted". You still don't have to interpret.

Comment: How, exactly, would you go about compiling a block like the above when you can't be sure if parts of it are data or code? Or, better yet, code like [$something {sum $b $c}]... which you don't know if the value of the variable $something is [eval] or [puts] (meaning the value in the curly braces could be code or data) until runtime.

Comment: The same way SBCL compiles `(EVAL '(+ 2 3))` or any other compiled language that supports metaprogramming. Code is data does not preclude compilation.

Comment: I was under the impression that SBCL is able to compile that because it can tell, at the time of compilation, that EVAL treats it's argument as code. Is it possible to redefine what EVAL (for every place it's used, even already defined functions) does at runtime?

Comment: "Is it possible to redefine what EVAL...does at runtime?". Yes, you can redefine what anything does at run-time using something like Lisp.

Comment: Interesting, then how does the compiler know whether to compile the input of a function to code or data, since it won't know which it is until it actually gets to the point where it runs the command?

Comment: It'll generate code for both with a run-time test to jump to the appropriate one. So it is really no different to any other control flow construct. If the code to be evaluated is generated at run-time then it will invoke the compiler at run time and jump into the newly generated code. I did this in HLVM where even the garbage collector is generated for types as you type them in: http://hlvm.forge.ocamlcore.org/

Comment: I tend to think that, if you have to have conditional logic in the compiled code to be able to handle every single argument to every command being either code or data, the final result is going to be... unwieldy. Add to that the fact that you point out that you need to be able to handle compiling code at runtime (pretty much an interpreter), and I'm not sure what I said is far off from what you're saying. Especially when you take into account things like compiling to bytecode (at runtime or not).

Comment: Yes, if you regard run-time compilation as interpretation then they are the same thing. I think of an interpreter as a program that executes another program directly without translating it into another language. That is a subjective definition not univerally held...