# List of variables defined in the code (c++)

Tags: c++

Does someone know if in C++ is there a function to get the name of all the variables defined in a code?

Example code:

```
int main()
{
   double Var1;
   double Var2;
   UnknownFunction();
}
```

In this case the function I'm searching for(UnknownFunction) should output a vector of strings containing "Var1" and "Var2".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And will all of the variables you're interested in be of the same type (`double` here)?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? Why do you think you need this?

Comment: There is no way to do that. If you tell us more about what you're trying to do, we might be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: And if possibile Aldo to provide the type and value of each one

Comment: There is no way to do this in C++. A compiler internally would have a list during compilation, but there's no way to access this information. Also, consider that a compiler, with optimizations on, gets rid of many variables anyway.

Comment: I want to create an equation solver which takes the formula from string, so when it is found in the string a symbol (not a number) it search in the variabile list to get the value. Is it possibile to do?

Comment: What you're looking for is called reflection, and C++ doesn't support this. Some scripting languages like Python and Javascript do. Instead, you make your own symbol table, and have a map of strings to values. Your formula solver can use the symbol names to get and set values in the table.

Comment: @FGP92 You have asked an X-Y question.  The thing you really want to do is in your last comment - you'd do better to ask that question.  Do you really mean "_equation solver_" or more simply an "_expression evaluator_"?  I say more simply - it is still not that simple.  What you need is a string to value look-up or hash table, the variables declared in your C code are irrelevant to the variables used in your expression evaluator.

Comment: @FGP92 *I want to create an equation solver* -- Even if it is what you stated, an equation solver, this is not a trivial thing to write.  And let's say that C++ *did* have reflection, I fail to see how that would make this any more easier to develop.

Comment: What you really want is probably a [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to map variable names to theier respective values. The variables in your program are something else entirely than variables in an equation that you would take as input.

Comment: The problem with an X-Y question such as this, is when you get the answer (which is basically "no you can't") you are no further forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When C++ code has been compiled to machine code, the symbol names are resolved to explicit memory addresses by the compile/link process and are not available to the program at run time, so the question makes no real sense.

Symbolic information is retained for use in a debugger and a debugger can present all variables in scope.

Comment: The question is about C++. Also there's no such thing as "a compiled language".

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Corrected C++.  Not sure what your point about ["compiled language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) is - perhaps a little pedantic?  The term serves my purpose for this discussion - in the sense that the compiler generates machine code where variable names are not retained.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Show me a C interpreter that's not an online "compiler"

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 : Nonetheless your objection has led me to modify the text for a perhaps clearer and as a side-effect hopefully less objectionable text.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I already thought to create a vector of objects "variabile" each containing name and value and then creating a map that links the name to the corresponding value. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @JoelTrauger No, not "for the sake of it", we value correctness and factual accuracy here on Stack Overflow. If you are not interested in that (the assertion in your comment, "without exception", is _incorrect_) then there are other places to go, but casting aspersions doesn't add anything either, and I'll ask you to refrain from that behaviour in the future. Have a good day.

Comment: @JoelTrauger I appreciate your support, but since avoidance of the contested term does not in fact detract from the answer, I suggest the discussion cease.  It is an improvement without the term even if it was fine with it. The "no such thing as a compiled language" thing is dealt with at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440297/there-is-no-such-thing-as-a-compiled-language-or-interpreted-language

Comment: @FGP92 : Your comment probably belongs on the question rather than my answer - where there are no "suggestions" - they are all in comments to the _question_.  That said, the comments are all intended to encourage you to improve the question rather than to answer it.  You might either do that or ask a new question so that a more fully formed and useful answer might be provided than is possible in comments.  As it stands your question may get closed or attract down-votes.